# SQL join to next available date if date is not valid

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2016

Looking for some help on a query. I have a customer table logging customers linked to a base location. And a location table detailing addresses for a location at a particular point in time.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
   [ID] [int] NULL,
   [Date of Transfer] [datetime] NULL,
   [Old Location] [int] NULL,
   [New Location] [int] NULL)


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customer] (ID, [Date of Transfer], [Old Location], [New Location])
VALUES  (1, '2016-07-01 00:00:00.000', 1001, 2200),
        (1, '2017-11-25 00:00:00.000', 2200, 3078),
        (1, '2018-01-01 00:00:00.000', 3078, 8500),
        (2, '2016-02-27 00:00:00.000', 5578, 9901),
        (2, '2017-06-22 00:00:00.000', 9901, 9001);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Location](
    [Location Code] [int] NULL,
    [Location Address] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Date From] [date] NULL,
    [Date To] [date] NULL)


INSERT INTO [dbo].[Location] ([Location Code], [Location Address], [Date From], [Date To])
VALUES (1001, 'Logan Street', '1998-02-01 00:00:00.000', '2017-07-21 00:00:00.000'),
    (2200, 'Ashdown Avenue', '2014-01-31 00:00:00.000', NULL),
    (3078, 'Chessington Court', '2009-05-11 00:00:00.000', '2018-03-30 00:00:00.000'),
    (8500, 'Cambridge Green', '2018-01-15 00:00:00.000', '2018-02-15 00:00:00.000'),
    (8500, 'Blair Road', '2018-02-15 00:00:00.000', NULL),
    (5578, 'Aberdeen View', '2000-11-19 00:00:00.000', '2017-05-13 00:00:00.000'),
    (9901, 'Tay Road', '2013-02-02 00:00:00.000', '2018-01-22 00:00:00.000'),
    (9001, 'Wellington Way', '2015-02-16 00:00:00.000', '2018-02-22 00:00:00.000');
```

I'm trying to join both tables to give me the address of the location linked to a customer are the point they transfered to another location. This works fine for most using the following

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[Date of Transfer]
  ,[Old Location]
  ,O.[Location Address]
  ,O.[Date From]
  ,O.[Date To]
  ,[New Location]
  ,N.[Location Address]
  ,N.[Date From]
  ,N.[Date To]
FROM [dbo].[Customer]
Left Join [dbo].[Location] O on [Old Location] = O.[Location Code] and ([Date of Transfer] >= O.[Date From] OR O.[Date From] is NULL)  and ([Date of Transfer] <= O.[Date To] or O.[Date To] is NULL)
Left Join [dbo].[Location] N on [New Location] = N.[Location Code] and ([Date of Transfer] >= N.[Date From] OR N.[Date From] is NULL)  and ([Date of Transfer] <= N.[Date To] or N.[Date To] is NULL)
ORDER BY [ID], [Date of Transfer] ASC
```

The problem I have is that the location table has sometimes been updated late therefore a customers transfer does not join to any valid location. I'd like to add a clause that checks the date the location is valid. So in my above example I'd like to link customer 1's transfer to 8500 to the Cambridge Green address updated around 1 month after the transfer. Does anyone have any idea how I can do this.

Current example output

```
ID          Date of Transfer        Old Location Location Address                                   Date From  Date To    New Location Location Address                                   Date From  Date To
----------- ----------------------- ------------ -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ------------ -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
1           2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 1001         Logan Street                                       1998-02-01 2017-07-21 2200         Ashdown Avenue                                     2014-01-31 NULL
1           2017-11-25 00:00:00.000 2200         Ashdown Avenue                                     2014-01-31 NULL       3078         Chessington Court                                  2009-05-11 2018-03-30
1           2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 3078         Chessington Court                                  2009-05-11 2018-03-30 8500         NULL                                               NULL       NULL
2           2016-02-27 00:00:00.000 5578         Aberdeen View                                      2000-11-19 2017-05-13 9901         Tay Road                                           2013-02-02 2018-01-22
2           2017-06-22 00:00:00.000 9901         Tay Road                                           2013-02-02 2018-01-22 9001         Wellington Way                                     2015-02-16 2018-02-22
```

The last row for customer 1 has not been linked to a location because no location is listed for the period during the transfer. I'd therefore like to check what the next location address is for that location code since the transfer date.

NOTE: The location table can have more than one address per location (over different periods. I therefore can't use a simple join.

Desired output.

```
ID          Date of Transfer        Old Location Location Address                                   Date From  Date To    New Location Location Address                                   Date From  Date To
----------- ----------------------- ------------ -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ---------- ------------ -------------------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
1           2016-07-01 00:00:00.000 1001         Logan Street                                       1998-02-01 2017-07-21 2200         Ashdown Avenue                                     2014-01-31 NULL
1           2017-11-25 00:00:00.000 2200         Ashdown Avenue                                     2014-01-31 NULL       3078         Chessington Court                                  2009-05-11 2018-03-30
1           2018-01-01 00:00:00.000 3078         Chessington Court                                  2009-05-11 2018-03-30 8500         Cambridge Green                                    2018-01-15 2018-02-15
2           2016-02-27 00:00:00.000 5578         Aberdeen View                                      2000-11-19 2017-05-13 9901         Tay Road                                           2013-02-02 2018-01-22
2           2017-06-22 00:00:00.000 9901         Tay Road                                           2013-02-02 2018-01-22 9001         Wellington Way                                     2015-02-16 2018-02-22
```

Comment: Could you post actual and expected output for the data in your table?

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[Date of Transfer]
  ,[Old Location]
  ,O.[Location Address]
  ,O.[Date From]
  ,O.[Date To]
  ,[New Location]
  ,N.[Location Address]
  ,N.[Date From]
  ,N.[Date To]
FROM [dbo].[Customer]
Left Join [dbo].[Location] O on [Old Location] = O.[Location Code] and ([Date of Transfer] >= O.[Date From] OR O.[Date From] is NULL)  and ([Date of Transfer] <= O.[Date To] or O.[Date To] is NULL)
Left Join [dbo].[Location] N on [New Location] = N.[Location Code] and ([Date of Transfer] >= N.[Date From] OR N.[Date From] is NULL or N.[Date To] is NULL)  and ([Date of Transfer] <= N.[Date To] or N.[Date To] is NULL)
ORDER BY [ID], [Date of Transfer] ASC
```

Comment: Thanks again but you may be misunderstanding my issue. I need to join on a value between the 2 dates. If now value matched between the 2 dates I need to then look for the location with the closest date after the transfer date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT [ID]
  ,[Date of Transfer]
  ,[Old Location]
  ,O.[Location Address]
  ,O.[Date From]
  ,O.[Date To]
  ,[New Location]
  ,N.[Location Address]
  ,N.[Date From]
  ,N.[Date To]
FROM [dbo].[Customer]
Left Join [dbo].[Location] O on [Old Location] = O.[Location Code] and ([Date of Transfer] >= O.[Date From] OR O.[Date From] is NULL)  and ([Date of Transfer] <= O.[Date To] or O.[Date To] is NULL)
Join [dbo].[Location] N on [New Location] = N.[Location Code] and ([Date of Transfer] >= N.[Date From] OR N.[Date From] is NULL)  and ([Date of Transfer] <= N.[Date To] or N.[Date To] is NULL)
ORDER BY [ID], [Date of Transfer] ASC
```

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't take into account the possibility that another location with that code may also be included in the table with a different address.

Comment: can you share your desired output with the complete case?